# Type 'myClass[]' provides no match for the signature '(): myClass[]'. [2322]

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to get a list of projects from an API, but I am getting the following error:

```
Type 'TestFields[]' provides no match for the signature '(): TestFields[]'. [2322]
```

Below is my code

```ts
export class ProjectOperation extends TestFields {
  projectList: TestFields[];

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
    private _services: DeoService
  ) {
    super();
    // this.projectList = new TestFields()
  }

  getProjects(): TestFields[] {
    // below is the line where i am getting error 
    this._services.getProjects('/api/project/getProject').subscribe(res => {
      this.getProjects = res;
    }); // this is the area i am getting error
    return this.projectList;
  }
}
```

and this is my getProject code

```
public getProjects(api: string): Observable<TestFields[]> {
    return this._http.get<TestFields[]>(api);
  }
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `this.getProjects` to a variable?

Comment: You should just return the projects from your service's `getProjects` method, instead of reassigning.

Comment: @Edric, I want to perform some operation at that variable later. thats why.. what will be thebest possible solution? can you suggest?

Comment: As what I said, in your `getProjects` method, just return `this._services.getProjects`, since you're not actually doing anything to `projectList` (or at least according to your code).

Comment: What is `TestFields` BTW? Is it a class?

Comment: yes it is a class

Comment: I think it would help if you could create an MCVE on StackBlitz.

BTW, `return this.projectList;` would run even before the Observable is unwrapped and it's value is assigned to `projectList`  so eventually if you haven't initialized `projectList` anywhere, it would be `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

You can return the method from your service instead of assigning the result of the method to a variable and then returning it:

```ts
export class ProjectOperation extends TestFields {
  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
    private _services: DeoService
  ) {
    super();
  }

  getProjects(): TestFields[] {
    return this._services.getProjects('/api/project/getProject');
  }
```

}

Comment: sir i have edited the code for you. please have look.